# Spring XML property not being assigned correctly

Tags: java, spring

I have the following:

```
public class DifferentClass {
    Map<String,AnotherClass>someMap;
}

public class AnotherClass {
    Class<?> dataType;

    public void setDataType(Class<?> val) {
        this.dataType=val;
    }
}

public class A {
    ...
    public static class B {
        ...
    }
    ...
 }
```

The following spring bean configuration:

> <bean id="springRefName" class="my.project.path.to.DifferentClass">
>   ...
>   <property name="someMap">
>   <map>
>   ...
>   <entry key="someName">
>   <bean class="my.project.path.to.AnotherClass">
>   <property name="dataType" value="my.project.path.to.A$B" />
>   </bean>
>   </entry>
>   ...
>   </map>
>   </property>
>   ...
>   </bean>

The problem I'm having is when I call dataType.getCanonicalName() I'm only getting my.project.path.to.A. Which leaves me believing that Spring is truncating the name when it converts to a Class to assign to AnotherClass.dataType. I have tried it with both the $ and a .

Comment: Can you try: "`A&dollar;B`", `"A\$B"`, "`A&#36;B`" or "`A$$B`"?

Comment: Nope, A&dollar;B, A\$B, A$$B resulted in no class found errors and A&#36;B failed to reference the inner-class.

Comment: We throw an IllegalArgumentException at a certain point if we can't find an interface from set of interfaces for a class. The static inner-class implements one of these interfaces and the outer-class doesn't.

Comment: For the record I've also tried A.B.

Comment: I tried your sample with Spring 3.1.2 and both versions work cleanly -  `my.project.path.to.A$B` and `my.project.path.to.A.B` and the canonical name comes as `my.project.path.to.A.B`, not sure why you would be seeing a different behavior

Comment: Just looked at my pom file and I believe we're using an older version of spring. Might be a bug they fixed?

<spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
<org.springframework.spring-context.version>3.0.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.spring-context.version>

Comment: Found the error. It was in another file where I actually had the file info. Boils down to a typo on my part causing a script error where it auto-generates some file descriptors based on user inputs.